# How to playing looping background audio in a Windows Phone 8 app (without using the BackroundAudio service)??

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I am creating a XAML/C# based Windows Phone 8 app and I would like to have some simple looping background music playing throughout the app to enhance user experience, however I'm not sure how to do this.

All the methods I have found so far have been unsuitable - MediaElement only seems to work on one page (therefore not continuous across pages of the app), XNA SoundEffect methods don't work at all and the native API's are for C++ only. I'm not looking for complex capabilities or for the sound to continue playing outside the app.

The reason I don't want to use the BackgroundAudio method is that this continues music outside the app and provides the user with the music overlay bar to change the sound, which I do not want.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post the solution I found below for anyone interested (similar to the one suggested in the comments).

This code would be placed in the App.xaml's Application Resources tags, to define the page style for the MediaElement (make sure you change the file path in Source to where your own sound file is located):

```
<Style  x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                    <Grid>
                        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Source="/Assets/Sounds/backgroundmusic.wav" Volume="1" AutoPlay="True" />
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You also need `RootFrame.Style = Resources["RootFrameStyle"] as Style;` underneath the line `RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();` in your App.xaml.cs file. What this does is attach the style we just defined for the MediaElement to your application's root frame, which is the frame in which your app's pages are displayed.

To make the audio loop indefinitely, you will need to create a MediaEnded handler in your MediaElement style:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Source="/Assets/Sounds/backgroundmusic.wav" Volume="1" AutoPlay="True" MediaEnded="MediaPlayer_MediaEnded" />
```

You can then place the following code into the MediaEnded event created in your App.xaml.cs file:

```
private void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement ctrl = (MediaElement)sender;
        ctrl.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        ctrl.Play();
    }
```

Please note that this is not a perfect solution as there is a small time gap in between the loop stopping and starting from the beginning again. However, this can be made less obvious by using an audio loop that fades out at the start and at the end. If you want a seamless and more flexible solution, you may be better off using one of Windows Phone's native audio solutions detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. One question, is it possible to control that MediaElement from any of the pages (as it is in the template)?

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a WPFnot sure if it could help you in WP8 app.

App initialization:

```
Music = new MediaPlayer();
Music.Open(new Uri("Sounds/SalusEstudiantv5.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
Music.MediaEnded += MusicEnded;
Music.Play();


private void MusicEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Music.Stop();
Music.Play();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it seems like the Music functions aren't recognised by the Windows Phone 8 SDK (tried lots of namespaces). Thanks anyway

Comment: Music its just my variable, i did not include the declaration, what you need is the  MediaPlayer()

Answer (score 0):

You can put a MediaElement in the Frame, so it's available for all Pages. To do so, you need to set the Frame's Style whenever the Frame is created in App.xaml.cs. And somewhere you need to define the Style:

```
<Style x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                <Border x:Name="ClientArea" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Grid>
                        <MediaElement x:Name="FakeBackgroundAudioPlayer" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>                       
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```